# How to track parallel progress and completion in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

The scenario is that I want my code to iterate all line items on an order and insert them separately in queues for parallel processing.  Products would pass through multiple queues before finally landing in a data store.

I know I can attach the Order ID with the products so that they all come together in the end but my question is:

Is there a way to tag products so that RabbitMQ understands they are part of a group and report on progress or completion?

I know could use code to setup an array to track progress/completion or use the data store.  I'm just wondering if there is some facility I can use with RabbitMQ before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no logical grouping of items in RabbitMQ, beside the queue they are on.

You need to implement that logic in your application.